# Using pgeocode in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the distance from a UK post code to another UK post code for over 4,000,000 rows of data.

I have imported a csv file with 4,000,000+ rows including UK postcode into a pandas dataframe.

I have then attempted to use pgeocode https://pypi.org/project/pgeocode/ to calculate for each row the distance from the base Post code. But I am not having much success.

**Updated with minimal working example**

Trying to calculate distance (D) from A to B.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'A': ['S35 2PH', 'LS10 2RU', 'SK6 3DY'], 'B': ['EC1V 9LT', 'E4 8EJ', 'NG23 5DE']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

import pgeocode
dist = pgeocode.GeoDistance('GB')
df['D'] = dist.query_postal_code(df['A'], df['B'])
```

Results in following output error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-df12337a18f4> in <module>
      1 import pgeocode
      2 dist = pgeocode.GeoDistance('GB')
----> 3 df['D'] = dist.query_postal_code(df['A'], df['B'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2936         else:
   2937             # set column
-> 2938             self._set_item(key, value)
   2939 
   2940     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2998 
   2999         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3000         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3001         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3002 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3634 
   3635             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3636             value = sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   3637             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3638                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
    609 
    610     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 611         raise ValueError("Length of values does not match length of index")
    612 
    613     if isinstance(data, ABCIndexClass) and not copy:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Any help really appreciated. I am probably coming at this from completely the wrong angle. I tried using for loops but no joy. I am very much a beginner.

Many thanks,

Tom

Comment: The package works well on my machine for UK post codes. Can you provide a *minimal working example*?

Comment: Hi Thomas! It would be good, for the sake of posterity, if you could also include your code in the question.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you. Please see above updated question with minimal working example including code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query_postal_code` take 2 Python lists in parameter and not Numpy arrays provided by Pandas when you use `df['A']`. You should use `to_list` to convert the Numpy array into list so that the code works.

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'A': ['S35 2PH', 'LS10 2RU', 'SK6 3DY'], 'B': ['EC1V 9LT', 'E4 8EJ', 'NG23 5DE']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

import pgeocode
dist = pgeocode.GeoDistance('GB')
df['D'] = dist.query_postal_code(df['A'].to_list(), df['B'].to_list())
```

Here is the result on my machine:

```
          A         B           D
0   S35 2PH  EC1V 9LT  234.724473
1  LS10 2RU    E4 8EJ  257.754932
2   SK6 3DY  NG23 5DE   93.912263
```